# CSS - input field background color

Tags: css, input, hover, background-color

[image]

How can I change this purple color behind my input field? I already tried with `background-color` or with `:hover` but nothing happens. This is a `CORE UI Admin Template` and it's main color is purple but I want it to change with my own color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.yourclass:focus {
    border-color: green;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px green;
}
```

Though, you should probably find and change `box-shadow` and `border-color` colors in the original CSS file. You can use "inspect element" to find where it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input[type=text]:focus{box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #cccccc;} for changing the color

Answer (score 0):

it looks like outline! Try:
.yourclass{outline: unset!important;}
Or
.yourclass:focus{outline: unset!important;}